# How can I improve my Python code to apply to n nodes of a directed graph?

Tags: python, simulation, probability

With a four node graph (A, B, C, D) there are 6 potential edges; AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD. The probability that an edge is chosen is 0.2.

As there are only 38 possible combinations of edges that connect the graph, the code below can calculate the probability.

However, it is a manual entry of the combinations. So my problem is what if there are 6 nodes (A, B, C, D, E, F) with 15 possible edges, how could I alter my code to apply to n nodes.

With any number of nodes above 4, this code would not be feasible.

Any ideas on how to solve this without entering every possible combination of a connected graph?

```
def graph_sim(X):    
possible_edges = ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD'] 
distinct_connected_graphs = [
      ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD'], 
      ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD'], ['AB', 'AC', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD'], ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BD', 'CD'],
      ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'CD'], ['AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD'], ['AB', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD'],
      ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC'], ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BD'], ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'CD'],
      ['AB', 'AC', 'BC', 'BD'], ['AB', 'AC', 'BC', 'CD'], ['AB', 'AC', 'BD', 'CD'],
      ['AB', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD'], ['AB', 'AD', 'BC', 'CD'], ['AB', 'AD', 'BD', 'CD'],
      ['AB', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD'], ['AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD'], ['AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'CD'], 
      ['AC', 'AD', 'BD', 'CD'], ['AC', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD'], ['AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD'],
      ['AB', 'AC', 'AD'], ['AB', 'AC', 'BD'], ['AB', 'AC', 'CD'], ['AB', 'AD', 'BC'], 
      ['AB', 'AD', 'CD'], ['AB', 'BC', 'BD'], ['AB', 'BC', 'CD'], ['AB', 'BD', 'CD'],
      ['AC', 'BC', 'BD'], ['AC', 'AD', 'BD'], ['AC', 'BC', 'CD'], ['AC', 'AD', 'BC'],
      ['AC', 'BD', 'CD'], ['AD', 'BC', 'BD'], ['AD', 'BC', 'CD'], ['AD', 'BD', 'CD']
                            ]
directed_graph = [
    [edge for prob, edge in zip(np.random.uniform(low= 0.0, high= 1.0, size=6), possible_edges) if prob < 0.2]
    for i in range(X)]
connected_realisations = [i for i in directed_graph if i in distinct_connected_graphs]

print("-------------------------")
print("* The probability that a graph is connected in", X, "realisations is:", len(connected_realisations)/X)
print("* The number of connected graphs in", X, "realisations is:", len(connected_realisations))
return
graph_sim(2000)
```

Comment: I guess the way to resolve it is to make the `size` of your `np.random.uniform` dynamic. as well as the `prob`. Maybe by doing `size = len(possible_edges)` and `prob < 1/len(possible_edges)` (also, talking about it, isn't prob supposed to be under 0.16666666 for 6 possible edges  ? (1/6))

Comment: p= 0.2 is what decides whether an edge is used

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you want to create the set of distinct connected graphs. You can generate this by adapting [Prim's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm): 1. Start with single nodes; 2. iterate over the subgraphs created in the last step and create new subgraphs by choosing and adding an edge each; 3. prune the generated list of (sub)graphs by dropping duplicates.